# How can I execute a function right after an "await" request has been completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

This whole thing about Promises and async, etc. is driving me insane. I just need to run a function whenever I connect to the database. (This code works fine, but I can't know when the `await` is complete. Help!

```
async function connectToDB() {
    console.log("Connecting to database...");
    database = await pool.connect();
    // I want to run some function only after the connection has been made.
}
```

I'm working with node.js and postgreSQL as the database manager.

Comment: I don't get the question.  Does `pool.connect()` return a promise that resolves when it's done?  If so, just put your function call on the next line and it won't get called until `pool.connect()` resolves its promise.  If you're not using a version of your database where `pool.connect()` returns a promise, then you need to switch to a different module for your database that supports promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's been a long day, I didn't actually test that... (It works). How can I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `pool.connect()` return a promise that resolves when it's done, then you just put your function call on the next line right after the `await` and it won't get called until `pool.connect()` resolves its promise.

If you're not using a version of your database where `pool.connect()` returns a promise, then you need to switch to a different module for your database that supports promises.

And, of course, if the `pool.connect()` promise rejects, then it will skip the rest of the function (analagous to a `throw`) and the caller of your funiiton will see a rejection on the promise that your `async` function returns.

```
async function connectToDB() {
    console.log("Connecting to database...");
    database = await pool.connect();
    callSomeFunctionHere();         // this will happen after pool.connect() resolves
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Async functions return a `Promise` and when you `await` an async function, you're indicating that that the script should not continue until that function is complete

You can replace `// I want to run some function only after the connection has been made.` with your code and that code will only run after `pool.connect()` is completed.

You can also `await connectToDb()` as you've made it an async function as well.

```js
await connectToDb();
// other code that is run immediately after connectToDb finishes 

// --- OR ---

connectToDb().then(() => { 
    // other code that is run immediately after connectToDb finishes 
});
```